# Is an extension from the ExtensionFunctionDefinition class a modification under the terms of the MPL 2.0 license?

Tags: java, saxon

I would like to use SaxonHE (this open source solution is distributed under the MPL 2.0 licence) as the library in the commercial proprietary software. At the same time, I need functionality that allows me to call custom Java code from Xslt code. As far as I can see, such functionality is available in SaxonHE via the ExtensionFunctionDefinition class extension. Therefore, I want to clarify whether creating my own custom classes that extend the ExtensionFunctionDefinition class will be considered a Modification under the terms of the MPL 2.0 license?

Comment: Probably not, after all, you are not changing the library code, you are adding something to it for use in your code. If you release that modification you may have to make it available under the same license. (Double check the terms, I don't know what MPL requires.)

Answer (score 0):

**I Am Not A Lawyer.**

The definition of "modifications" in MPL 2.0 is:

> any of the following:
>
> any file in Source Code Form that results from an addition to,
> deletion from, or modification of the contents of Covered Software; or
>
> any new file in Source Code Form that contains any Covered Software.

When you extend a Java class, you typically create a new file that references the original; you don't modify the original. Your new file will contain some fragments of code that are the same as fragments in the original, namely the signatures of methods you are overriding; but I think it highly unlikely that anyone would interpret that as meaning that your extension "contains covered software".

Of course, if your extension copied significant chunks of the open source code, perhaps in modified form, then that would be different. But even then you can get around that easily enough, simply by classifying those files as open source, and keeping them separate from your proprietary code. It's worth noting that although the MPL requires you to make modified code available under the MPL, it doesn't have to be usable: you don't have to publish documentation or test material, in fact you don't even have to publish it in a form that will compile (it can contain calls on code that you don't publish).

But I repeat: **I Am Not A Lawyer.**